# Лямбда-выражения с переменным количеством параметров ошибка с2760

Tags: c++, lambda

Написать функцию, которая вычисляет минимальное значение списка аргументов произвольной длины с разными типами элементов списка. 
Выдаёт ошибку : C2760   синтаксическая ошибка: ожидался токен "<Нет данных>", а не "<Нет данных>"

```
   template <typename T>
inline T min(T t) { return t; }

template <typename T, typename ...P>
inline auto min(T t, P... p)
{   
    return [](auto a, auto b) { (b<a) ? return b : return a; }(t, min(p...));
}

int main()
{   
    std::cout << min(2,2.5,false,' ') << std::endl; 
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Тернарный оператор в лямбде описан неверно. Вместо

```
 (b<a) ? return b : return a;
```

скорее все вы подразумевали

```
 return (b<a) ?  b : a;
```

Кстати, необходимость в лямбда-выражении здесь довольна сомнительна. Ведь вполне можно обойтись и без нее:

```
template <typename T, typename ...P>
inline auto min(T t, P... p)
{
    auto next = min(p...);
    return (t < next) ? t : next;
}
```